# PUZZLE MAZE using probability - HOW TO

Tags: probability

is there an easier way to do this? perhaps a formula?[image]

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm to find all such paths? Or an algorithm to generate this maze in the first place? The latter is more in our wheelhouse for game development, since we're usually the maze-builders and our players the maze-solvers. For algorithms for solving a given maze, you might find the [Computer Science StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit, since they specialize in techniques for these types of logic & search problems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with PC game development. It instead may belong on [puzzling.se].

Comment: There is no easy formula to solve this. This is at least an NP-hard (and probably NP-complete) problem. The brute-force solution (with suggested optimisations) posted by Martin Frank is likely the best you're going to get. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness

Answer (score 0):

you could determine all paths to go through a grid (see [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rectangular-grid-walk-no-restriction/)).

[image]

there's a mini python implementation shown on [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rectangular-grid-walk-no-restriction/), so it seems pointless for me to post more from the blog

also it's obvious that you have to sum up the values for each path and validate it (is its sum 1?) ...

### EDIT

i've provided the python code for a 5x5 (m,n-grid) from [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rectangular-grid-walk-no-restriction/). You can use this as a guide for any other programming languages... this algorithm is really not hard to translate into whatever you need - details to this algorithm can be taken from the blog....

```
def dp(m, n, arr):
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 1
    if m < 0 or n < 0:
        return 0
    if arr[m][n] != 0:
        return arr[m][n]
    arr[m][n] = dp(m-1, n, arr) + dp(m, n-1, arr)
    return arr[m][n]

m = 5
n = 5
arr = [0] * (m + 1)
for i in range(m + 1):
    arr[i] = [0] * (n + 1)
    print(dp(m, n, arr))
```

Comment: do i really have to use python for it?

Comment: i am really trying to find a formula for it. ofcourse i can manually count all the paths and validate if it's one but i am trying to find an easier way for me to do that.

Comment: the algorithm is always the same no matter what language you choose...

Comment: you can calculate the sum of the path during creating if if it is not suitable(if it's > 1), you can skip this path.